# How to instantiate an implementation of interface?

Tags: c++, types, unreal-engine4

I have two properties:

```
UPROPERTY()
TScriptInterface<ICoordinateSystem> CoordinateSystem;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
TSubclassOf<UCoordinateSystem> CoordinateSystemType;
```

How can I instantiate CoordinateSystemType and store result to CoordinateSystem? I have tried different ways like

```
CoordinateSystem = NewObject<ICoordinateSystem>((UObject *) GetTransientPackage(), *CoordinateSystemType); 
CoordinateSystem = NewObject<UCoordinateSystem>((UObject *) GetTransientPackage(), *CoordinateSystemType);
CoordinateSystem = Cast<ICoordinateSystem>(NewObject<UCoordinateSystem>((UObject *) GetTransientPackage(), *CoordinateSystemType));
```

but none of them compiles saying something like it can't convert UObject* to ICoordinateSystem* or ICoordinateSystem* to UObject* in either NewObject or TScriptInterface = operator.
I was trying it in UE 4.11 and 4.12

Edit: For code

```
CoordinateSystem = Cast<ICoordinateSystem>(NewObject<UCoordinateSystem>((UObject *) GetTransientPackage(), *CoordinateSystemType));
```

I get error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: UE44X, Configuration: DebugGame_Game x64 ------
1>  Creating makefile for UE44X (working set of source files changed)
1>  Parsing headers for UE44X
1>    Running UnrealHeaderTool "F:\UE4\UE44X 4.12\UE44X.uproject" "F:\UE4\UE44X 4.12\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE44X\DebugGame\UE44X.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
1>  Reflection code generated for UE44X in 4,8843075 seconds
1>  Performing 2 actions (4 in parallel)
1>  UE44XGameMode.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.12\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\ScriptInterface.h(150): error C2664: 'void FScriptInterface::SetObject(UObject *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'ICoordinateSystem *' to 'UObject *'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.12\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\ScriptInterface.h(150): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>  F:\UE4\UE44X 4.12\Source\UE44X\UE44XGameMode.cpp(26): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'InterfaceType &TScriptInterface<InterfaceType>::operator =<To>(UObjectType *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              InterfaceType=ICoordinateSystem,
1>              To=ICoordinateSystem,
1>              UObjectType=ICoordinateSystem
1>          ]
1>  F:\UE4\UE44X 4.12\Source\UE44X\UE44XGameMode.cpp(26): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'InterfaceType &TScriptInterface<InterfaceType>::operator =<To>(UObjectType *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              InterfaceType=ICoordinateSystem,
1>              To=ICoordinateSystem,
1>              UObjectType=ICoordinateSystem
1>          ]
1>ERROR : UBT error : Failed to produce item: F:\UE4\UE44X 4.12\Binaries\Win64\UE44X-Win64-DebugGame.pdb
1>  Total build time: 11,90 seconds
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(37,5): error MSB3075: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.12\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" UE44X Win64 DebugGame "F:\UE4\UE44X 4.12\UE44X.uproject" -waitmutex" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: It shows this: http://pastebin.com/6BDcmX6W for code: `CoordinateSystem = Cast<ICoordinateSystem>(NewObject<UCoordinateSystem>((UObject *) GetTransientPackage(), *CoordinateSystemType));`

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are generally treated as classes that declare functions, but these functions are typically implemented in the subclasses.

In UE4, the IInterface is not an UObject.  You'll need to create a class that derives from your interface.

```
class MyClass : public UObject, public ICoordinateSystem
{
    //Overrides functions from ICoordinateSystem
    ....
};
```

You'll be able to instantiate MyClass.  To get a handle to MyClass's CoordinateSystem, use the Cast template...

```
MyClass* myClassInstance;
....
ICoordinateSystem* coordinateInterface = Cast<ICoordinateSystem>(myClassInstance);
```

Hopefully this article will help clarify how to work with interfaces:
https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Interfaces_in_C%2B%2B

Comment: InterfaceCast is deprecated. What is the point to use interfaces then? If you are right, you have no reason not use abstract class, cuz it's impossible to instantiate class w/ 2+ interfaces as both anyway.

Comment: Made corrections regarding the deprecated casting.

You can still instantiate objects that implements interface.  The purpose of interfaces is similar to components, where you can declare functions that may be used in multiple classes that are not related to each other.

A useful case of this is that you can declare a function that expects a pointer to that interface.  The function, itself, doesn't care what kind of object it is, it just cares that it implements the functions declared from that interface.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to get interface implementing type via property and instantiate it to TScriptInterface property?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely understand what you mean by getting an interface implementing type.

I'm guessing that you want to get a handle to an interface class much like UClasses, and then use its reference to instantiate an object of that particular type.  For example:  GetWorld()->SpawnActor(UCoordinateSystem::StaticClass()).  The interfaces affiliated to subclasses is evaluated at compile time, and cannot be modified during run time.  It's like trying to change an object's super class at run time.

I believe components are what you're looking for if that's the case.

Comment: No, I'm not. E.g.: I have some interface `IMyInterface` and some classes like `UMyClass : UObject, IMyInterface`. I want to get type of any of that classes via property like `TSubclassOf<SomeType>` or even `UClass` and instantiate it. Then I want to store it in some variable for later use. In last comment I've asked if it is only possible using abstract classes instead of interfaces.